# Javascript numeric variable comparison not working

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 2 Submit buttons. One is for `Approve` the other is for `Reject`.

The `HTML is`:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="sos_submit" id="sos_submit">

  <input type="text" name="qty_indented" value="<?php echo $qty_indented ?>" id="qty_indented" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="text" name="qty_approved" value="<?php echo $qty_approved ?>" id="qty_approved" />
  <input type="submit" name="da_approve" value="APPROVE" onclick="return submitForm(this)" />
  <input type="submit" name="da_reject" value="REJECT" onclick="return submitForm(this)" />

</form>
```

And my `submitForm(this)` Function looks like:

```
<script>
function submitForm (button){

    if (button.value == "APPROVE"){
        var qty_approved = document.getElementById("qty_approved").value;
        var qty_intended = document.getElementById("qty_indented").value;
        if (qty_approved <= 0){
            alert("Please Enter the Quantity for Approval!");
            submitOK = "false"; 
        }
        else if(qty_approved >= qty_intended){
            alert("Quantity Approved " + qty_approved + " Cannot be more than quantity intended " + qty_intended + " !");
            submitOK = "false";
        }
        if (submitOK == "false") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        confirm("Are you sure you want to REJECT the Voucher?");    
    }
}
</script>
```

Although its very simple code, but somehow not working properly.

Even though `qty_approved` is `LESS` than `qty_indented`, the `if()` statements are executing.

For example, if `qty_approved = 5` and `qty_indented = 10`, then the code should submit the form, but it is NOT. It is showing: `Quantity Approved 5 Cannot be more than quantity intended 10 !`

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: `.value` returns a **string**. `qty_approved >= qty_intended` performs string comparison.

Comment: They are getting compared as strings -- try to make them int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input boxes are string-based values.  You need to convert the values to integers using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var qty_approved = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty_approved").value, 10);
var qty_intended = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty_indented").value, 10);
```

At the moment it's comparing '5' to '10', and alphabetically '5' is greater than '10', which is why it's dropping into that condition.

Comment: That actually solved the issue! I will vote up when it allows me.